# RegistryValue Element of type multiString

Tags: wix, windows-installer

The WiX [doc](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registryvalue.html) says that if type is **MultiString** then we can specify actions, append, prepend, write(default).
what is mean by write action here? does it simply overwrites earlier entry, or adds with semicolon?
if it just overwrites earlier entry, how it is different from type "**string**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe **write** overwrites the existing value(s) whether string or multi string, and enforces whatever new string type is specified. **Multi string** is different from string because you can add a list of stings via the `<MultiStringValue>` element (a regular string value can not do this - it cannot have MultiStringValue child elements):

```
<RegistryValue Id="R3" Root="HKCU" Action="write" Key="Software\_WiXTest"
               Name="multi" Type="multiString" Value="samplemultistring">
    <MultiStringValue>test2.1</MultiStringValue>
    <MultiStringValue>test2.2</MultiStringValue>
</RegistryValue>
```

For multi string **prepend** adds the string at the start of the string list and **append** adds the string to the end of the string list. **Multi strings** are not semicolon delimited as far as I know, but a sequence of null-terminated strings, terminated by an empty string (`\0`). See [Registry Value Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

**Sample Multi String**: `String1\0String2\0String3\0LastString\0\0`, and how it looks in `regedit.exe` (with a contrasting regular string):

[image: View of a multi string in regedit.exe]

---

Just dumping some sample test markup - warts and all :-) - you can use for testing if you'd like:

```
<Component Feature="MainApplication" Id="HKCU" Guid="*">
  <RegistryValue Id="R1" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\_WiXTest" KeyPath="yes" 
                 Name="WiXWritten" Type="string" Value="R1 regular string">
  </RegistryValue>
  <RegistryValue Id="R2" Root="HKCU" Action="append" Key="Software\_WiXTest" 
                 Name="WiXWritten" Type="multiString" Value="R2 sample multistring">
      <MultiStringValue>test1.1</MultiStringValue>
      <MultiStringValue>test1.2</MultiStringValue>
      <MultiStringValue>test1.3</MultiStringValue>
  </RegistryValue>
  <RegistryValue Id="R3" Root="HKCU" Action="write" Key="Software\_WiXTest"
                 Name="WiXWritten" Type="multiString" Value="R3 sample multistring">
     <MultiStringValue>test2.1</MultiStringValue>
     <MultiStringValue>test2.2</MultiStringValue>
   </RegistryValue>
 </Component>
```

Some of the elements above will overwrite each other on install - as far as I understand that's what wasn't clear to you. Maybe dump this in your WiX source and give it a test spin.

By repeating several `RegistryValue` elements you can get the same effect as the `MultiStringValue` elements.

Try changing the last `RegistryValue` element's `Action="write"` to `Action="append"`. Now it adds to the existing multi string instead of overwriting it. It should become: `R2 sample multistring\0test1.1\0test1.2\0test1.3\0R3 sample multistring\0test2.1\0test2.2\0\0`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination. I will try given code snippets in my WiX source